# How much is $1^{\aleph _{0}}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm sorry for asking stupid questions, but I have not found an answer anywhere: do I think well that $1^{\aleph _{0}}={\aleph _{0}}$ and $1^{\mathfrak c}=\mathfrak c$?

Comment: How many maps $\Bbb N\to\{1\}$ are there? and $\Bbb R\to\{1\}$?

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: You seem to be computing $\kappa^1$ instead of $1^\kappa$.

Comment: See [Cardinal arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Cardinal_arithmetic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one function from $\Bbb N$ to $\{0\}$, the everywhere-$0$ function. But to specify such a function, you make $\aleph_0$ choices each with one option. Therefore, $1^{\aleph_0}=1$. Indeed, any cardinal $\kappa$ satisfies $1^\kappa=1$.

Answer (score 0):

For cardinals $\kappa$ and $\lambda$, by definition we have that the cardinal $\kappa^\lambda$ is the cardinality of the set of all functions from a set of cardinality $\lambda$ to a set of cardinality $\kappa$. If $\kappa=1$ there only is the constant function to the unique element of the set of size $\kappa=1$.

So $1^\lambda = \lambda$ for all non-empty cardinals $\lambda$.

Also, if $\lambda=0$, we only have $\emptyset$ as the domain of those function, and as a function is a subset of the Cartesian product (which is $\emptyset$ if one of the factors is $\emptyset$) we only have $\emptyset$ as such a function, regardless of $\kappa$. So $\kappa^0=1$ for all cardinals $\kappa$.